# Untrusted certificate HTTPs load failed on Swift5

Tags: swift, api, ssl

I am using swift. My API is Untrusted certificate.

my code:

```
AF.request(APICaller.POSTv2_URL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).response
    { response in
        switch(response.result)
        {
            case .success:
                do
                {
                    if let userInfo = response.data
                    {
                        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                        let userInfo = try decoder.decode(UserLoginData.self
                                                          , from: userInfo)
                        completion(.success(userInfo))
                        print("123")
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            case .failure: print("fail")
        }
    }
```

Error Log:

```
Connection 1: default TLS Trust evaluation failed(-9807)
Connection 1: TLS Trust encountered error 3:-9807
Connection 1: encountered error(3:-9807)
```

ScreenShot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0jxW.jpg)

I have read many articles on the Internet, but they can't solve it.

I hope there is a lot of detailed teaching how to solve it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `Allow Arbitrary Loads` just allows plain text connections but does not disable certificate checking:

> Set this key’s value to YES to disable App Transport Security (ATS) restrictions for all domains not specified in the NSExceptionDomains dictionary.
> Disabling ATS means that unsecured HTTP connections are allowed. HTTPS connections are also allowed, and are still subject to default server trust evaluation

Additionally this key is ignored since iOS 10:

> In iOS 10 and later and macOS 10.12 and later, the value of the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads key is ignored—and the default value of NO used instead

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads

As [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) offers trusted HTTPS certificate available for free you should use them instead of an untrusted certificate, then you don't have to modify anything on ATS and certificate checking.